# Mongo: export all fields data from collection without specifying fields?

Tags: mongodb

- I have over 100 fields and I am looking for a way so that I can just export the entire collection as CSV format
- The command-line is asking to provide all fields via

> -f [ --fields ] arg     comma seperated list of field names e.g. -f
>   name,age

- is there a way to get the entire collection like using dump but not in bson format?
- I need CSV data

Thank you

Comment: mongodb  have no export command for CSV dump? Even nowadays, 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a file with the field names (may be easier for you):

```
--fieldFile arg         file with fields names - 1 per line
```

In your case they might all be the same but the reason you have to specify the field names is because they could be different for every document however the field names in the csv must be fixed.

Answer (score 14):

In bash you can create this "export-all-collections-to-csv.sh" and pass the database name as the only argument (feel free to reduce this to a single collection):

```bash
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=",";

dbname=$1 #put "database name" here if you don't want to pass it as an argument

collections=`mongo $dbname --eval "rs.slaveOk();db.getCollectionNames();" --quiet`;
collectionArray=($collections);

for ((i=0; i<${#collectionArray[@]}; ++i));
do
    keys=`mongo $dbname --eval "rs.slaveOk();var keys = []; for(var key in db.${collectionArray[$i]}.findOne()) { keys.push(key); }; keys;" --quiet`;
    mongoexport --db $dbname --collection ${collectionArray[$i]} --fields "$keys" --csv --out $dbname.${collectionArray[$i]}.csv;
done

IFS=$OIFS;
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://username:password@connect_string --collection sources --type csv --fields _id,authors,author_1,author_2,author_3,author_4,author_5,author_6,author_7,author_8,author_9,author_10,year,title,publication,page_numbers,section,full_citation --out c:/users/owner/literature.csv

This worked for me, but all the field names did have to be listed. How I got around typing them over and over again was I put the command in a notebook .txt file and cut and pasted so I only had to type them once. It is very important not to put spaces in or between the field names and not to put the list of field names in quotes or anything. If you put it in quotes it will not include the data from the field with quotation mark in it.

This works for Atlas. The user has to have admin and backup privileges and the mongo export utility is from MongoDB Database Tools.